# Need help in mod 1000000007

Tags: c++

I'm stuck in a problem in which I need to calculate something like:

((500!)/(20!x20!x20!x20!...)) mod 1000000007

I understand how to calculate 500!%1000000007 but I am not sure on how to distribute that operator in division.

I am currently trying to write a code which cancels the denominators by its numerator by its factors. But I am not sure if it is a good approach to this.

I just need a mathematical way of solving these kind of problems(mod1000000007) as they are regularly encountered in programming competitions and would help me to prepare for Google Code Jam.

Comment: What does `(x/y) mod z` even mean? Is it: "find a number, which if multiplied by `y`, will be equal (mod `z`) to `x`?"

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Think of how you would compute `500! / (20! * 20! * 20! * ...)` normally.

Don't multiply everything out and divide at the end. Do your divisions in the middle. Then combine this with the modulus reductions from your previous question.

**Method 2:**

[Prime factorize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factor) `500!` and `20!`. Then subtract out the prime factors of `20! * 20! * 20!` (or how ever many of them you have) from the prime factors of `500!`.

Then rebuild the number by multiplying back the remaining factors together. (while taking modulus along the way to keep the number from getting large)

**Method 3:**

If `1000000007` (or whatever modulus) is prime, you can do divisions using the [modular inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

Compute `20! mod 1000000007`. Then compute it's modular inverse and multiply it into `500! mod 1000000007`.

Comment: thanks a lot. Method3 helps a lot.  Could you also suggest me a good book to improve my math skills, which are essential to programming i.e. difficult to solve otherwise.

Comment: I don't read books. I use Google and Wikipedia. This math topic that you've stumbled upon is called "Number Theory". But that's a very large topic that no single book can cover. You can also try searching for "Modular Arithmetic".