# how to calculate 2^n modulo 1000000007 , n = 10^9

Tags: math, matrix, eigenvector, eigenvalue, exponentiation

what is the fastest method to calculate this, i saw some people using matrices and when i searched on the internet, they talked about eigen values and eigen vectors (no idea about this stuff)...there was a question which reduced to a recursive equation 
f(n) = (2*f(n-1)) + 2 , and f(1) = 1,
n could be upto 10^9....
i already tried using DP, storing upto 1000000 values and using the common fast exponentiation method, it all timed out
im generally weak in these modulo questions, which require computing large values

Comment: What language/tool? In general, a PowMod or ModPow function performs this sort of calculation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Fastest method is pencil and paper: `140625001`

Comment: This is a recurring topic, just search for this special number, http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=1000000007. For instance, in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220416/need-help-in-mod-1000000007 or the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289495/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-compute-large-power-of-2-modulo-a-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f(n) = (2*f(n-1)) + 2 with f(1)=1
```

is equivalent to

```
(f(n)+2) = 2 * (f(n-1)+2)
         = ...
         = 2^(n-1) * (f(1)+2) = 3 * 2^(n-1)
```

so that finally

```
f(n) = 3 * 2^(n-1) - 2
```

where you can then apply fast modular power methods.

Comment: For the German-speaking ones interested, I vaguely remember the topic covered in the textbook "Algorithmische Zahlentheorie" by Otto Forster.

Answer (score 2):

Modular exponentiation by the square-and-multiply method:

```
function powerMod(b, e, m)
    x := 1
    while e > 0
        if e%2 == 1
            x, e := (x*b)%m, e-1
        else b, e := (b*b)%m, e//2
    return x
```

Comment: this is amazing solution

Comment: what is b ,e ,and m in this case can anyone explain

Comment: B is the base, e is the exponent, and m is the modulus.

Answer (score 0):

C code for calculating 2^n

```
    const int mod = 1e9+7;

    //Here base is assumed to be 2
    int cal_pow(int x){
        int res;
        if (x == 0) res=1;
        else if (x == 1)    res=2;
        else {
            res = cal_pow(x/2);
            if (x % 2 == 0) 
                res = (res * res) % mod;
            else
                res = (((res*res) % mod) * 2) % mod;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe yes but it still requires some modification though. right?

Comment: didn't check the result, but seeing it what it does,  you should remove it from time being

Comment: Made required changes and it doesn't produce direct results!