# Library math.h using fmod and own implementation

Tags: c++, fmod, math.h

```
//test.cpp
fmod( pow(2.0,127),467 );// Return result as 132 <-- correct answer
```

When i using my own implementation

```
int mod( int dividend , int divisor ){
return (dividend % divisor + divisor ) % divisor;
}

int a = mod ( pow(2.0,127),467 );// Wrong result , 441

//or direct use
int a = pow(2.0,127);
int b = a%467 // Will return wrong result , -21
```

i want to get answer 132, fmod does it, but why my implementation cannot get the correct answer?

Comment: Duplicate or related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287144/3088138, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23846699/3088138

Answer (score 3):

The problem, as addressed by Ivan, is that you are exceeding the bounds of an integer.  Unfortunately there is no native type which can hold 2^127 (Excluding using two 64 bit results as a synthetic 128 bit int).

However, fortunately for you, in this case you more likely what you want is powmod.  Powmod is a pow function which computes mod at the same time as the power (as the name would suggest).  Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
int powmod(int b, int e, int m)
{
    int result = 1;
    while(e > 0){
        if(e & 1){
            result *= b;
            result %= m;
        }
        b *= b;
        b %= m;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this case, b is your base, e is your exponent, and m is your mod.  So in this case `powmod(2, 127, 467)` returns 132 -- your intended answer.  Hope this helps, and if you're dealing with a lot of big numbers and modular arithmetic I suggest you read an article or two on congruency of modular operations.

Edit: Fixed a grammar typo.

Answer (score 0):

`fmod` takes double arguments, whereas your `mod` function takes ints. 2^127 does not fit into an int so it gets wrapped in some unexpected way.

Comment: so isn't i just need to chage to float or long int instead of int?

Comment: `long long` is still not large enough to fit 2^127. However, if you switch to floats or doubles, you won't be able to use `operator %` so you'd have to come up with a different implementation. (I think this is actually the reason `fmod` exists - because you can't use `%` instead.)