# check multiple of n value as modular congruence

Tags: c++, cryptography

Now i want to check that if value

```
int a = pow(9.0,100);
int b = 81;
int c = 547;
```

when i use a - b, the value should be can divide by c without remainder;

```
if( (a-b) % 547 == 0 )
     cout << "Correct" << endl;
else
     cout << "Wrong" << endl;
```

but the output always go wrong and i see website links. the answer should be correct.
Link can be reference to thread here : [How to calculate modulus of large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers)

but mine one when do the congruence modulo it's involve minus sign. so dont know how to write the algorithm

Comment: It's equivalent to checking (9^100) = b mod c, and you can use the other answer.

Comment: but i need to minus the -81 . so how to count it?

Comment: `(a-81)%547=0` is the same as `a%547=81` (assuming a is non-negative, which it is here).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287144/3088138, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23846699/3088138 and likely many others.

Answer (score 2):

9^100 is about 10^95, so it overflow int. Instead of calculating 10^95 and then modulo you can calucate it with normal int with something like this:

```
int c=1;
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) 
    c = (c * 9) % 547;
```

so c value is always below 547. You can also speed it up by using binary power method.

For your second question - easiest method to compute mod value for negative value is to do this with this code:

```
int mod(int a, int n) {
    int res = a % n;
    if (res < 0) res = res + n;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: i know how to calculate the pow and modulo already.. but my first variable have to minus the b .. and your calculation doesn't involve any minus?

Comment: try function from my answer: mod(a-b, 547)

Comment: even without the pow() function ?

Answer (score 1):

9^100 is likley of out range for int. So you should calculate powermod(9,100,N) where N can be int or use class that can store arbitrary size integer

Comment: The point is that you can reduce intermediate results so that you never get numerical overflow. One has `(a*b) mod N == ((a mod N)*(b mod N)) mod N` so that there are never numbers larger than N² during the computation of powermod.