# Fast multiplication of large numbers modulo n

Tags: java, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help in mod 1000000007 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions)

I have a set of numbers for which i want to compute total product modulo 1000007. e.g if my array contains 1000 numbers then i need to compute the following.

```
int product = 1;
for(int i=0;i<Array_Max;i++)
  product = product * Array[i]
```

then product modulo 1000007 = ?

Is there any algorithm to optimize the above pseudo code ? Right now i am unable to store the product because of overflow.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: The `1000007`... Is this related the problem from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions

Comment: Investigate the BigInteger and BigDecimal classes.

Comment: I'm math challenged.  Are we saying that `(a mod x) * (b mod x) * (c mod x) == ((a*b*c) mod x)` ?

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Not quite.  We're saying that `((a * b) mod x) * c) mod x == (a * b * c) mod x`.

Comment: Alok, what is the largest value you expect to be in `Array[]`?  This will help us determine the type of the result.

Comment: All numbers in the array is less than 1000007

Comment: @Tony we are calculating something like (a[0]*a[1]*a[2]...a[n-1])modulo 1000007. Overflow will appear once the product exceeds the max limit of integer or long whatever we choose.

Answer (score 3):

Use `long`s for the product - this will be enough to hold the result of multiplying two integers.

You also will want to compute the modulo on each iteration so that you avoid overflow (this is safe to do from a mathematical perspective, as it doesn't change the result modulo 1000007 at the end).

You could also use `BigInteger`s if you wanted, but it would be much slower.

Comment: How do you know the `long` is big enough for the multiplication of 2 integers?

Comment: @TonyEnnis: Because `int` is 32-bit and `long` is 64-bit.

Comment: @TonyEnnis What Oli says. Or, in another words, [MAX_INTEGER * MAX_INTEGER = 4.6 × 10^18](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282^31-1%29+*+%282^31-1%29), but [MAX_LONG is 9.2 × 10^18](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2^63-1)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If the OP is asking this question, I would think his use of an `int` is suspect to begin with.

Comment: +1 `long` it is, according to a clarification from the OP.