# how to calculate (A*B*C)%10000007 where A,B,C can be at maximum 10^18

Tags: modulus

how to calculate (A*B*C)%10000007 where A,B,C can be maximum 10^18

Comment: Using maths. Did you have a specific language in which you were trying to implement this? If so, you'll need to tag the question with that language, or this is doomed to be closed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the sections named ["
What kind of questions can I ask here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and ["What kind of questions should I not ask here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). I also recommend you read the sites http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ and http://sscce.org/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help in mod 1000000007 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Let I = 10000007, so

- A = n1 * I + X1
- B = n2 * I + X2
- C = n3 * I + X3

A * B => (n1 * I + X1) (n2 * I + X2) => n1 * n2 * I^2 + n1 * X2 * I + n2 * X1 * I + X1 * X2
Only X1 * X2 can't div by I

Hence, A * B % I === X1 * X2 % I === (A % I) * (B % I) % I

Therefore (A * B * C) % I === [(A % I) * (B % I) % I] * (C % I) % I

Comment: Use long long in C/C++, long in Java etc. to hold the 10^18.