# Why am I getting a negative value?

Tags: c

There is some mistake in power function of my code it returns correct answer for small values but gives wrong answer for large values.

```
#include<stdio.h>
long long MOD= 1000000007;
long long power(long long i,long long j)
{
        if(j==0)
                return 1;
        long long d;
        d=power(i,j/(long long)2);
        if(j%2==0)
                return (d*d)%MOD;
        else
                return (d*d*i)%MOD;
}

int main()
{
        long long inv=1;
        inv=power(25,MOD-2)%MOD;
        printf("%lld\n",inv);
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate the problem?

Comment: What problem are you having? Compilation error? Runtime error? Wrong results? If the last, what do you expect the result to be for some value, and what do actually get?

Comment: no errors.... just wrong answer

Comment: What's the input that leads to wrong answer, then?

Comment: @PeterK.: `y` has type `long long` so `y/2` and `y/(long long) 2` are guaranteed to be the same thing.

Comment: @timrau: inv=power1(25,MOD-2)%MOD;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions

Comment: power function still returns -ve value.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Correct! My mistake.

Comment: @user2205153 why do you accept my answers and then come back on your decision? Was there something incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

range of signed long long is -2^63 to (2^63 - 1) and the last bit is used to store sign . In your case when multiplication of large numbers is evaluated than your result will overflow and 64th bit of number(which stores sign) will get value 1 (which means -ve value).

That's the reason you are getting negative value as output.

[Read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 1):

Your arithmetic overflowed the values representable in a `long long` in your C implementation.

Also, you are working on a challenge problem or homework which has been discussed numerous times on Stack Overflow, as you can see by searching for “1000000007”.

Comment: I have no problem with algorithm.I am having problem with c .In python I am getting correct result of same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with `(d*d*i)%MOD;`, because more than one operation without modulo is incorrect, ***taking precision and risk of overflowing in account***. To be strictly correct you need to write

```
 return ((d*d)%MOD * i)%MOD;
```

Even in this case I assumed `i == i%MOD`

EDIT: I take an example :

```
log2((MOD-1)x(MOD-1)x25) = log2(1000000006x1000000006x25) = 64.438
```

Which means you will be overflowing during your computation with this input.