# Calculating 1^X + 2^X + ... + N^X mod 1000000007

Tags: algorithm, algebra, number-theory, modulo

Is there any algorithm to calculate `(1^x + 2^x + 3^x + ... + n^x) mod 1000000007`? 
Note: `a^b` is the b-th power of a.

The constraints are `1 <= n <= 10^16, 1 <= x <= 1000`. So the value of N is very large.

I can only solve for `O(m log m)` if `m = 1000000007`. It is very slow because the time limit is 2 secs.

Do you have any efficient algorithm?

There was a comment that it might be duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions), but it is definitely different.

Comment: @TobySpeight No, it is definitely different. 1^x, 2^x..., n^x is mod exponential, and I want to find FAST ALGORITHM because n <= 10^16 and mod = 10^9+7.

Comment: n^x mod m is the same as ((n^(x-1) mod m) * (n mod m)) mod m; (a + b) mod m is the same as ((a mod m) + (b mod m)) mod m.

Comment: @TobySpeight In my slow algorithm, I have to take mod about 10^10 times. But it is very slow because the time limit is 2sec. I only want to find fast algorithm.

Comment: @Vatine But n is very large!!! Read the constraints. If I naively calculate 1^x, 2^x, 3^x,..., n^x, it will take much time to calculate!

Comment: @TobySpeight Does that really help? See there is up to 10,000,000,000,000,000 terms in parentheses, each of them requiring up to 1,000 multiplications in the simplest, naive raising to the power algorithm. Reducing the number of `mod` s by a factor of 5 or 50 doesn't seem to significantly reduce the amount of computation.

Comment: @CiaPan Please note that 10^9+7 is a prime.

Comment: Oh, and n^x % m is the same as ((n%m)^x) % m. All of this falls out as natural consequences of moduli. Thus you only need to calculate up to 1000000007 exponentiations, do a bit of division, another mod, and some multiplication and addition to find the total.

Comment: Give a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula. If your problem comes from a challenge site like HackerRank, I bet the inner product always simplifies to an integer and that there is a way to get rid of the global factor as well.

Comment: @FabianPijcke It seems like a good method to solve, but I don't know how to calculate B[0], B[1],..., B[x].

Comment: There are several equivalent definitions. Note that you have to assume B[0] = -1/2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition

Comment: ((Woud like to make it an answer, alas the question got closed, so I can only post this as a comment.)) For small `n` you can compute the sum directly in reasonable time. For large `n` I think you can find such pairs of numbers, which add up to 1000000007 (for example 1 and 1000000006, 7 and 1000000000...). Those numbers equal 1 and (–1) mod 1000000007, respectively, so they cancel in summation – and so do their respective powers. You can skip them then, so you'll have to directly calculate no more than 1000000007 terms of the sum...

Comment: @CiaPan Only two votes are needed to reopen. If it can, please post as an answer!

Comment: You never need to calculate more than 1000000007 terms in the sequence, it's periodic. 10^16 is a red herring.

Comment: @n.m. I am saying that 1,000,000,007 term is much large because calculating a^b mod m takes O(log b) times.

Comment: `log b` is at most 10 here.

Comment: @n.m. The time limit is 2 sec. Do you think that 1000000007*10 iteration can be in 2 sec?

Comment: Probably not, but you can precompute some results for a significant speedup.

Comment: I was wrong, you don't need to compute up to 1000000007 terms! If `n > 1000000007/2` there are some numbers between `1` and `n` which make sum `1+n` equal 1000000007; so you have to compute no more than `1000000007/2` i.e. 500000004 terms. Additionally `(a**x) * (b**x)` equals `(a*b) ** x`, so it's enough to compute `p**x` for primes only, then compute remaining terms by multipliying powers of appropriate primes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can *sum up* the series

```
1**X + 2**X + ... + N**X
```

with the help of [Faulhaber's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html) and you'll get a polynomial with an `X + 1` power to compute for arbitrary `N`.

If you don't want to compute *Bernoulli Numbers*, you can find the the polynomial by solving `X + 2` *linear equations* (for `N = 1, N = 2, N = 3, ..., N = X + 2`) which is a slower method but easier to implement.

Let's have an example for `X = 2`. In this case we have an `X + 1 = 3` order polynomial:

```
    A*N**3 + B*N**2 + C*N + D
```

The linear equations are

```
      A +    B +   C + D = 1              =  1 
    A*8 +  B*4 + C*2 + D = 1 + 4          =  5
   A*27 +  B*9 + C*3 + D = 1 + 4 + 9      = 14
   A*64 + B*16 + C*4 + D = 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 = 30
```

Having solved the equations we'll get

```
  A = 1/3
  B = 1/2
  C = 1/6
  D =   0
```

The final formula is

```
  1**2 + 2**2 + ... + N**2 == N**3 / 3 + N**2 / 2 + N / 6
```

Now, all you have to do is to put an *arbitrary large* `N` into the formula. So far the algorithm has `O(X**2)` complexity (since it doesn't depend on `N`).

Comment: But unfortunately x might be 1000... Solving linear equation can be O(X^3), but I think it is slow. I am checking about Faulhaber's Formula right now.

Comment: @square1001: if you have to be very fast, I suggest precomputing *Bernoulli Numbers* (up to `1000`); it's not an easy task (like linear equations solving) but in this case you'll get the polynom almost ready to use.

Comment: I checked about Bernoulli number, and finally understood that B[1], B[2],..., B[x] for O(x^2). So this problem can solve for O(N^2) !

Comment: @square1001: In `O(X**2)`, to be true, it doesn't depend `N` (number of items to sum), but of power `X` they should be raised

Comment: Now I'll implementate it.

Comment: @square1001: good luck! Be careful: you have to work with *fractions*

Comment: Implementated. I got Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways of speeding up modular exponentiation. From here on, I will use `**` to denote "exponentiate" and `%` to denote "modulus".

First a few observations. It is always the case that `(a * b) % m` is `((a % m) * (b % m)) % m`. It is also always the case that `a ** n` is the same as `(a ** floor(n / 2)) * (a ** (n - floor(n/2))`. This means that for an exponent <= 1000, we can always complete the exponentiation in at most 20 multiplications (and 21 mods).

We can also skip quite a few calculations, since `(a ** b) % m` is the same as  `((a % m) ** b) % m` and if m is significantly lower than n, we simply have multiple repeating sums, with a "tail" of a partial repeat.

Comment: But your algorithm has to calculate 1^x, 2^x, ..., 1000000006^x. It has over 10^9 terms, so you have to iterate over 10^10 times. So, I think it can't pass because the time limit is 2 secs.

Comment: @square1001 Just tested a NOP loop on my laptop, takes ~0.1 seconds to iterate 10 ** 10 times and that is likely dominated by "fork" and "exec".

Comment: This becomes *much* easier if *x* is odd, because, for example, `1000000006` is congruent to `-1`, so `1^x` and `1000000006^x` cancel out, and so do many other terms. I don’t see a shortcut if *x* is even, though.

Comment: And if x is known in advance, you could build a closed formula for the (non-mod) sum of exponentials. But, yes, you can probably collapse this to "calculate `500000003 ** x` % m; multiply by  `floor(n / m)`; loop for i from 1 to n % m, exponentiate and sum"

Comment: @Vatine 500000003 is cancelled by 500000004 for odd x. Therefore for odd x and n=m the sum equals zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think Vatine’s answer is probably the way to go, but I already typed
this up and it may be useful, for this or for someone else’s similar
problem.

I don’t have time this morning for a detailed answer, but consider this.
`1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + n^2` would take O(*n*) steps to compute directly.
However, it’s equivalent to `(n(n+1)(2n+1)/6)`, which can be computed in
O(1) time. A similar equivalence exists for any higher integral power
*x*.

There may be a general solution to such problems; I don’t know of one,
and Wolfram Alpha doesn’t seem to know of one either. However, in
general the equivalent expression is of degree *x+1*, and can be worked
out by computing some sample values and solving a set of linear
equations for the coefficients.

However, this would be difficult for large *x*, such as 1000 as in your
problem, and probably could not be done within 2 seconds.

Perhaps someone who knows more math than I do can turn this into a
workable solution?

Edit: Whoops, I see Fabian Pijcke had already posted a useful link about [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula) before I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something easy to implement and fast, try this:

```
Function Sum(x: Number, n: Integer) -> Number
  P := PolySum(:x, n)
  return P(x)
End

Function PolySum(x: Variable, n: Integer) -> Polynomial
  C := Sum-Coefficients(n)
  P := 0
  For i from 1 to n + 1
    P += C[i] * x^i
  End
  return P
End

Function Sum-Coefficients(n: Integer) -> Vector of Rationals
  A := Create-Matrix(n)
  R := Reduced-Row-Echelon-Form(A)
  return last column of R
End

Function Create-Matrix(n: Integer) -> Matrix of Integers
  A := New (n + 1) x (n + 2) Matrix of Integers
  Fill A with 0s
  Fill first row of A with 1s

  For i from 2 to n + 1
    For j from i to n + 1
      A[i, j] := A[i-1, j] * (j - i + 2)
    End
    A[i, n+2] := A[i, n]
  End
  A[n+1, n+2] := A[n, n+2]
  return A
End
```

### Explanation

Our goal is to obtain a polynomial `Q` such that `Q(x) = sum i^n for i from 1 to x`. Knowing that `Q(x) = Q(x - 1) + x^n` => `Q(x) - Q(x - 1) = x^n`, we can then make a system of equations like so:

```
d^0/dx^0( Q(x) - Q(x - 1) ) = d^0/dx^0( x^n )
d^1/dx^1( Q(x) - Q(x - 1) ) = d^1/dx^1( x^n )
d^2/dx^2( Q(x) - Q(x - 1) ) = d^2/dx^2( x^n )
                           ...                            .
d^n/dx^n( Q(x) - Q(x - 1) ) = d^n/dx^n( x^n )
```

Assuming that `Q(x) = a_1*x + a_2*x^2 + ... + a_(n+1)*x^(n+1)`, we will then have `n+1` linear equations with unknowns `a1, ..., a_(n+1)`, and it turns out the coefficient `cj` multiplying the unknown `aj` in equation `i` follows the pattern (where `(k)_p` = `(k!)/(k - p)!`):

- if `j < i`, `cj` = `0`
- otherwise, `cj` = `(j)_(i - 1)`

and the independent value of the `i`th equation is `(n)_(i - 1)`. Explaining why gets a bit messy, but you can check the proof [here](https://github.com/fcard/PolySum/blob/9dd498f9aa5996f3a430c2dbb4f0da2955b939f2/Proof/english.pdf).

The above algorithm is equivalent to solving this system of linear equations. 
Plenty of implementations and further explanations can be found in https://github.com/fcard/PolySum. The main drawback of this algorithm is that it consumes a lot of memory, even my most memory efficient version uses almost `1gb` for `n=3000`. But it's faster than both SymPy and Mathematica, so I assume it's okay. Compare to [Schultz's method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320260), which uses an alternate set of equations.

### Examples

It's easy to apply this method by hand for small `n`. The matrix for `n=1` is

```
| (1)_0   (2)_0   (1)_0 |     |   1       1       1   |
|   0     (2)_1   (1)_1 |  =  |   0       2       1   |
```

Applying a Gauss-Jordan elimination we then obtain

```
|   1       0      1/2  |
|   0       1      1/2  |
```

Result = `{a1 = 1/2, a2 = 1/2}` => `Q(x) = x/2 + (x^2)/2`

Note the matrix is always already in row echelon form, we just need to reduce it.

For `n=2`:

```
| (1)_0   (2)_0   (3)_0   (2)_0 |     |   1       1       1       1   |
|   0     (2)_1   (3)_1   (2)_1 |  =  |   0       2       3       2   |
|   0       0     (3)_2   (2)_2 |     |   0       0       6       2   |
```

Applying a Gauss-Jordan elimination we then obtain

```
|   1       1       0       2/3 |      |   1       0       0       1/6 |
|   0       2       0         1 |  =>  |   0       1       0       1/2 |
|   0       0       1       1/3 |      |   0       0       1       1/3 |
```

Result = `{a1 = 1/6, a2 = 1/2, a3 = 1/3}` => `Q(x) = x/6 + (x^2)/2 + (x^3)/3`

The key to the algorithm's speed is that it doesn't calculate a factorial for every element of the matrix, instead it knows that `(k)_p` = `(k)_(p-1) * (k - (p - 1))`, therefore `A[i,j]` = `(j)_(i-1)` = `(j)_(i-2) * (j - (i - 2))` = `A[i-1, j] * (j - (i - 2))`, so it uses the previous row to calculate the current one.