# algorithm to get power sum of natural numbers

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I am using python pow(n,k,mod) to get the power sum of natural numbers, but not getting perfect time complexity.
what i used

```
mod = 10**9+9
total = 0
for i in range(2, n):
    x = pow(i, k, mod)
    total += x
    total = total%mod
return total
```

can u suggest any aglorithmic approach to solve power sum

```
( 1^k + 2^k + 3^k + 4^k .... n^k ) mod 1000000009
```

where k ranges from 1 to 1000 and n belong to natural number 1

Comment: And what is the perfect time complexity in your opinion? Show the code that you used.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I got the feeling from the equation that it could possibly be solved by some FFT approach What do you think (You seem to have more experience in this field)?

Comment: I see the edit so the equation is `1^k + ... + n^k mod 1000000009` (I edited your question with it so if not the case edit it back). So you do not need `bigints`.  As it is ongoing contest then just hint for speedup: you should decompose the therms so you can compute non prime `i` from prime `i` to significantly lower the count of multiplications needed.... Also you should start with `total = 1` as you skip `1^k` in the `for` loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating 1^X + 2^X + ... + N^X mod 1000000007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695283/calculating-1x-2x-nx-mod-1000000007)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to avoid recalculation of large powers. For example `16^k` is `(2^k)^4`. You already calculated `2^k` so you can lookup it in a table, or --using a look-ahead strategy-- you can calculate all powers of say `2` beforehand.