# C++ - GMP library error with % operator

Tags: c++, gmp

This is my code. I am trying to **multiply two very large numbers** **(maximum digits can be 100000)** and the present the **result as modulo of 10^9 + 7**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

long long int rem = 1000000007;

int main() {

    mpz_class A, B, res;

    cin>>A>>B;

    res = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=B; i++)
        res = res*A;

    res = res % rem;
    cout<<res<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

But I get this **error** when I compile it:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator%’ (operand types are ‘mpz_class {aka __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>}’ and ‘long long int’)
     res = res % rem;
```

Here A and B can be as large as below respectively:

> 74543987529435983745230948023948 6498573497543987543985743989120393097595572309482304

**EDIT:**

```
/*Header files same as prev*/
mpz_class rem (1000000007);

int main() {

    mpz_class A, B, res;
    cin>>A>>B;
    res = A ^ B;     // Using "^" to denote exponentiation since we have used
    res = res % rem; // "+" and "%" instead of mpz_sum and mpz_mod functions
    cout<<res<<"\n";

return 0;
}
```

**The ERROR message is:**

```
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::~__gmp_expr()':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::__gmp_expr()':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1488: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1488: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1488: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `std::istream& operator>><__mpz_struct [1]>(std::istream&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>&)':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:2039: undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, __mpz_struct*)'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:2039: undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, __mpz_struct*)'
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `__gmp_binary_xor::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*, __mpz_struct const*)':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:846: undefined reference to `__gmpz_xor'
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `__gmp_binary_modulus::eval(__mpz_struct*, __mpz_struct const*, __mpz_struct const*)':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:763: undefined reference to `__gmpz_tdiv_r'
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `std::ostream& operator<< <__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>(std::ostream&, __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]> const&)':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:2033: undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, __mpz_struct const*)'
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::~__gmp_expr()':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear'
/ccqd5nye.o:/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1523: more undefined references to `__gmpz_clear' follow
/ccqd5nye.o: In function `__gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>::init_ui(unsigned long)':
/usr/include/gmpxx.h:1465: undefined reference to `__gmpz_init_set_ui'
```

Comment: Can you show us the *full* error message please.  The compiler will tell you what the possible overloads are.

Comment: Incidentally, you do know that GMP has this functionality built in?  See https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html

Comment: Final comment:  If B can be 6498573497543987543985743989120393097595572309482304, the for loop will never end (int will overflow before it reaches B), even if you make `i` be of type `mpz_class`, the loop will not end before the earth is destroyed by the sun becoming a red giant.

Comment: Don't [include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: Also see [Need help in mod 1000000007 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169167/need-help-in-mod-1000000007-questions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: GMP does not handle `long long`.

Comment: How can i use exponentiation with mpz_class for C++ because mpz_powm is for C and is therefore declared for mpz_t data type

Comment: @MartinBonner I have corrected that mistake and now i plan on using exponentiation to generate the result, can you help with that?

Comment: `^` does a xor, not exponentiation! And you can use C function in C++, see the end of https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html. By the way you need to link with libgmpxx.

Comment: Some day we will add a `pow` overload in gmpxx, and some later day we will optimize `pow(a,b)%m` to use the relevant C function, but that's not available now.

Comment: @MarcGlisse So what should i do now?

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal Read the other comments...

Comment: I think there is error on definition of rem

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguous overload error message means that there are multiple  implementations for `%` between `mpz_class` and `long long int`. I expect the compiler has found multiple ways to promote `long long int` to `mpz_class`, so that it can eventually call `%` between two instances of `mpz_class`.

The simplest way to resolve this is to change the types of the arguments so they match without the compiler having to change anything.

Try declaring the modulus as `mpz_class`:

```
mpz_class rem(1000000007);
```

Comment: Hey! It would be great if you could add a bit of explanation to the answer. While this seems to have helped the asker, it has been flagged for being a code-only answer.

Comment: @ZeMoon It just assigns "rem" the data type of C++ GMP library so that when the arithmetic operations are performed they are performed on similar data types, since GMP is defined for very very large numbers, it operates differently and hence type matching is important.....but this is my inference.

Comment: As I said in my comment, GMP does not handle long long. The possibilities that g++ found are converting the long long to long, unsigned long, float, double, etc (all are bad).

Answer (score 0):

First code is better to fix the error,  I supposed that there is error in definition of rem;
Please try it>

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

mpz_class rem = 1000000007;

int main() {

    mpz_class A, B, res;

    cin>>A>>B;

    res = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=B; i++)
        res = res*A;

    res = res % rem;
    cout<<res<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator%’ (operand types are ‘mpz_class {aka __gmp_expr<__mpz_struct [1], __mpz_struct [1]>}’ and ‘long long int’)
This error occupied because there is no operator this: `mpz_class operator% (mpz_class a, long long d)`

If you wanna to use long long for rem, you should define this operator.